# Compute $\frac{d}{dx(t)}\int_0^Tx(\tau)^TAx(\tau)d\tau$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

I need to compute:

$$
\frac{d}{dx(t)}\int_0^Tx(\tau)^TAx(\tau)d\tau,
$$

where $t\in (0,T)$, $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Using Leibniz differentiation under an integral sign, I have:

$$
\frac{d}{dx(t)}\int_0^Tx(\tau)^TAx(\tau)d\tau = \int_0^T\frac{dx(\tau)^TAx(\tau)}{dx(t)}d\tau,
$$

My course notes say this equals $Ax(t)$, which is almost as if:

$$
\int_0^T\frac{dx(\tau)^TAx(\tau)}{dx(t)}d\tau = \int_0^TAx(\tau)\delta(\tau-t)d\tau
$$

But I am not sure whether this is true or if something else tells us that it is $=Ax(t)$. Thanks for helping!

Comment: If $x$ is only a function of one parameter, how do you expect the integral's solution would be something other than a number? And thus its derivative would be zero. Otherwise, please show as: $x(t,\tau)$

Comment: No, $x$ is really only a function of one parameter. I am 100% certain the result is not zero, however.